# Can't change pivot title and pivot item header in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to make a basic app using the Pivot App template. Primarily, I went about modifying the existing data model and have been successful at binding what I needed displayed to the ListView within the pivot, but the pivot title and pivot item header are giving me a strange problem:

Initially, the template set the pivot title to "MY APPLICATION" and the two pivot item headers to "first" and "second" respectively. I didn't want a pivot title so I simply got rid of that property, and I over-wrote the pivot item header strings to "all tracks" and "favorites" respectively (as needed in my app). This was a very elementary task but the problem is that even though the changes reflect in the designer, at runtime when I deploy my app I'm still getting the "MY APPLICATION" pivot title and "first" and "second" pivot item headers. I've gone through the template code numerous times and haven't seen any other code that overwrites these properties anywhere, but for some reason the app is still retaining those initial values.

In the designer, everything's fine:

[image: In the designer:]

At runtime, the old pivot title and pivot item headers mysteriously reappear:
[image: Deployed on phone:]

The XAML code for the pivot:

```
       <Pivot x:Uid="Pivot" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="pivot" CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True">
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="60" Width="200">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="LightBlue" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" FontSize="45" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <PivotItem
            x:Uid="PivotItem1"
            Margin="19,14.5,0,0"
            Header="all tracks"
            DataContext="{Binding FirstGroup}"
            CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True">
            <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
            <ListView
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
                ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Name="MusicItemIcon" Margin="0,0,10,0" Source="/Assets/Icons/MusicIcon.png" Width="40" Height="40" />
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                                <TextBlock
                                    Text="{Binding Title}"
                                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                    Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="1"
                                    CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True"
                                    Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"
                                    FontSize="22"
                                    Margin="0,0,19,0"/>
                                <TextBlock
                                    Text="Dummy Description"
                                    TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                                    Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="2" 
                                    CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True" 
                                    Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}"
                                    FontSize="13"
                                    Margin="0,0,19,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <PivotItem
            x:Uid="PivotItem2"
            Margin="19,14.5,0,0"
            Header="favorites"
            DataContext="{Binding SecondGroup}">
            <!--Double line list no text wrapping-->
            <ListView
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
                Loaded="SecondPivot_Loaded"
                ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Name="MusicItemIcon" Margin="0,0,10,0" Source="/Assets/Icons/MusicIcon.png" Width="40" Height="40" />
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                                <TextBlock
                                    Text="{Binding Title}"
                                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                    Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="1"
                                    CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True"
                                    Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"
                                    FontSize="22"
                                    Margin="0,0,19,0"/>
                                <TextBlock
                                    Text="Dummy Description"
                                    TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                                    Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="2" 
                                    CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True" 
                                    Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}"
                                    FontSize="13"
                                    Margin="0,0,19,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in your resources.resw file. Your pivot items are set up to localize their names from that file via the x:uid tags:

```
        x:Uid="PivotItem1"
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue.